# AR отображение предмета по координатам

Tags: javascript, phonegap, mobile-development, mobile

Приветствую!

Только начал интересоваться мобильной разработкой, до этого делал только веб-сервисы. Появилась идея сделать небольшое приложение и заодно научиться делать что то на мобилки.

Выбор пал на phonegap, т.к. через phonegap Build можно написав один код создать приложение сразу под Android и iOS.

Прошу помощи, может кто сделать "скелет/прототип/пример" кода/приложения, чтобы по указанным координатам при наведении камерой на это место (ранее нужно задать координаты некого предмета) я увидел предмет.

Нашел, что это можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки wikitude, но я в этом пока не силен.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то очень давно я сделал на JavaScript подобие PockemonGO только без GPS. Может пригодится вам. Сразу скажу, что код там может быть не очень хороший, писалось на скорую руку.

Репозиторий: https://github.com/kadymov/pockemon-go-experiment

На фото - скрин браузера (на телефоне позади должен быть фон с камеры)

Покрутить камеру можно в дебагере хрома во вкладке Sensors.

Если не увидите ничего в браузере то либо надо запустить http сервер и с него смотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись! Обязательно посмотрю :)